# Virtual table is exactly created for which class in Diamond Inheritance?

Tags: c++

Consider the below code snippet:

```
class A
{
};

class B:public virtual A
{
};

class C:public virtual A
{
};

class D:public B,public C
{
};

int main()
{
    cout<<sizeof(A)<<" "<<sizeof(B)<<" "<<sizeof(C)<<" "<<sizeof(D));
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the [output](http://ideone.com/U362b) as:

```
1 4 4 8
```

The size of classes `B` and `C` is 4 bytes due to the creation of `vptr`. Does it mean that `virtual table` is created for classes `B` and `C`? What about `A`?

In general, **for which classes the compiler exactly creates the `virtual table` in diamond inheritance?**
**Is the decision for creating virtual table is compiler specific?**

Please answer in the context of the above example or any other better example.

Comment: Even the implementation of `virtual` function resolution is compiler specific. There doesn't need to be a `virtual table` but there most likely will be. You should specify your compiler.

Comment: To be specific, i am using ideone(gcc-4.3.4).

Comment: `More Effective C++` has some detail on this; `Item 24: Understand the costs of virtual functions, multiple inheritance, virtual base classes, and RTTI`. Don't have time to go through it all, but it is suggesting that only 3 vptrs may be needed, one of them can be shared. (And of course, that doesn't mean any implementation follows what he says).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, classes with virtual bases require some type of vtable or equivalent. You need some mechanism to look up the actual base subobject at runtime! (Remember that the virtual base subobject is the responsibility of the *most-derived* object, not of the directly inheriting one.)

Answer (score 0):

If the compiler generates VTABLES, he will for ANY class that needs one (contains virtual functions, ...).

**A** doesn't need a VTABLE => size == 1 [minimum size]

**B** needs one             => size == 4 [you're on 32bit...]

**C** needs one too         => size == 4

**D** needs one too         => size == 8 (2 entries, one for each VTABLE D is referring to)

Answer (score 0):

Virtual tables will be created for B, C and D. While B and C will have one VPTRs each, D will have 2 VPTRs. One pointing to B part of VTable and another pointing to C part of VTable.

Note: VTable is not mandatory and compilers are allowed to provide their own implementation as long as the inheritance relationships can be modeled properly. (however most of the compilers implement VTables)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that says the compiler *has* to create a `vptr` for any class. That said, in real life compilers do generate `vptr`s for two reasons:

1. Virtual dispatch (obvious)
2. RTTI, for example as required by `dynamic_cast` (not as obvious)

Typically, an entry in the `vtable` for the class will point to some kind of "type information" structure that provides enough information for RTTI to work.

It is this same information that allows the compiler to work out what to do if you e.g. cast any of `B*`, `C*`, `D*` to `A*`, so for `B` and `C` a `vptr` is needed. `D` simply aggregates both of them.